# Symplectic manifolds and almost complex structures

Tags: almost-complex

On a symplectic vector space $(V,\omega)$ with an inner product $g$, one can construct a canonical almost complex structure using polar decomposition. If $(M,\omega)$ is a symplectic manifold with a Riemannian metric $g$, one can use this construction to construct an almost complex structure $J_p$ on each tangent space $T_pM$ of $M$ for all $p\in M$.  Why is this construction smooth?

This problem is equivalent to the following matrix problem.  Suppose $B$ is a positive definite symmetric matrix which depends smoothly on a parameter $t$ in some open interval $(a,b)$.  Then there exists a unique positive definite symmetric matrix $S$ such that $S(t)^2 = B(t)$ for $t\in (a,b)$.  Why does $S$ depend smoothly on $t$?

Comment: For your matrix problem: that’s just the inverse function theorem for the smooth bijective submersion (hence diffeomorphism) $X \rightarrow X^2$ (from positive definite symmetric matrices to themselves), isn’t it?

Comment: I think you're right. Let $Z$ denote space of pos. def. symm. matrices. Let $\psi: Z\rightarrow Z$ be the map which sends $X\rightarrow X^2$.  $\psi$ is a diffeo.  Then $S = \psi^{-1}(B)$ is also smooth as the composition of two smooth functions.  Sounds good. Thanks!